# How to discretize a signal?

Tags: python, signal-processing, discretization

If I have a function like below:

> G(s)= C/(s-p) where s=jw, c and p are constant number.

Also, the available frequency is wa= 100000 rad/s. How can I discretize the signal at ∆w = 0.0001wa in Python?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "discretize"?

Comment: To convert a continuous signal into an equivalent discrete signal for the purposes of easier calculation. Or making a continuous signal to the digital signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.arange` to accomplish this:

```
import numpy as np

wa = 100000
# np.arange will generate every discrete value given the start, end and the step value
discrete_wa = np.arange(0, wa, 0.0001*wa)

# lets say you have previously defined your function 
g_s = [your_function(value) for value in discrete_wa]
```

Comment: Note that you'd probably use a vectorized function instead of looping over the numpy array in most circumstances, otherwise you'll be slowing down your code a lot.